# AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1638 on Windows 2012

Tags: sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012, appfabric

When I reinstall the AppFabric 1.1, Why I'm getting this error "AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1638".? on windows server 2012

> ERROR_PRODUCT_VERSION 1638    Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs in Control Panel.

Please find below the error message

```
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  ===== Logging started: 2016-05-20 15:53:31+01:00 =====
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  File:             c:\9a6b404fe782aa890e7e0d\setup.exe
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  InternalName:     Setup.exe
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  OriginalFilename: Setup.exe
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  FileVersion:      1.1.2106.32
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  FileDescription:  Setup.exe
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  Product:          Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server AppFabric
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  ProductVersion:   1.1.2106.32
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  Debug:            False
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  Patched:          False
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  PreRelease:       False
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  PrivateBuild:     False
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  SpecialBuild:     False
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  Language:         Language Neutral
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  OS Name:                   Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  OS Edition:                ServerStandard
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  OSVersion:                 Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  CurrentCulture:            en-US
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  Processor Architecture:    AMD64
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  Event Registration Source :    AppFabric_Setup
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1.0 Upgrade module.
2016-05-20 15:53:31, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed.
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1 Upgrade pre-install.
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed, not taking backup.
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Executing C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe with commandline -iru.
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Return code from aspnet_regiis.exe is 0
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Windows features successfully enabled.
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Process.Start: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\9a6b404fe782aa890e7e0d\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi" ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\a.Sainathan.Balasund\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2016-05-20 15-53-42).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\a.Sainathan.Balasund\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2016-05-20 15-53-42).log" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Process.ExitCode: 0x00000666
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1638
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Error                 Setup  
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1638
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Error                 Setup  
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Core.SetupException: AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1638
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.GenerateAndThrowSetupException(Int32 exitCode, LogEventSource logEventSource)
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.Invoke(LogEventSource logEventSource, InstallMode installMode, String packageIdentity, List`1 updateList, List`1 customArguments)
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.InstallSelectedFeatures()
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.Install()
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Client.ProgressPage.StartAction()
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  === Summary of Actions ===
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Required Windows components   :  Completed Successfully
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  IIS Management Console            :  Completed Successfully
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server  :  Failed
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Hosting Services          :  Failed
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Cache Client          :  Failed
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Hosting Administration            :  Failed
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update  :  Skipped
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update          :  Skipped
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  
2016-05-20 15:53:42, Information           Setup  ===== Logging stopped: 2016-05-20 15:53:42+01:00 =====
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that application do not have proper repair(upgrade?) mechanism working. Not familiar with AppFabric itself but in order to have it reinstalled I guess you will have to remove it through ARP and install again. Just make sure to backup necessary configuration.

You can also find some details in installer log: `C:\Users\a.Sainathan.Balasund\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2016-05-20 15-53-42).log`

On the other hand, you can take installer msi. From your log I can see:

> Process.Start: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\9a6b404fe782aa890e7e0d\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi" ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\a.Sainathan.Balasund\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2016-05-20 15-53-42).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\a.Sainathan.Balasund\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2016-05-20 15-53-42).log" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US

Copy it from `c:\9a6b404fe782aa890e7e0d\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi` somewhere safe during error message is shown and close the installer.

Then start original MSI and try running it manually (like just by double-clicking) it should run in maintenance mode and perform repair/reinstall.

You can also try initiate repair/reinstall from Add-remove programs if corresponding buttons are available there but If they are not than most likely installer do not have it configured correctly.

Comment: There is no AppFabric instance in this server but it showing the similar error during installation and no uninstall exe in add/remove programs.

Comment: This message is shown because some application with same productcode is already installed. It can be that it was installed once long time ago, or that some other app have same productcode (case which can occur like one time in a billion or even more rare=) ) extract mentioned msi, use Oraca or Insted-it to find what productcode this msi have. Try searching this productcode in registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\<ProductCode> and the same with WOW632 if you have 64bit OS)